# datamapper many-to-many table name

Tags: ruby, datamapper

I'm making blog service with datamapper and defined Article and Tag model like below.

```
class Article
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial

  has n, :tags, :through => Resource
end

class Tag
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial

  has n, :articles, :through => Resource
end
```

And these relationships defined in 'article_tags' table.

- How is that table name defined?
- Why not 'articles_tags'?
- Can I change table name without create custom table model class?

sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Tag
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial

  has n, :articles, 'Article',:child_key => [:article_id]
end
```

See: [Customizing Associations](http://datamapper.org/docs/associations.html).